# Firestore generates an index create error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection that I'm trying to query. The query generates an index error along with a URL to fix it. The URL looks something like the following:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[project-id]/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgV1c2VycxoPCgtpbnN0aXR1dGlvbhACGgwKCGxhc3RuYW1lEAIaDQoJZmlyc3RuYW1lEAIaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAg

When I copy and paste the URL into a browser, I get a Firebase (not Firestore) logo that appears like a butterfly, and then the screen goes blank. When I look at the browser console, I get an uncaught javascript error, actually a whole error object, though this part of it seems most relevant:

"Requested entity was not found"

Meanwhile, when I decode the url's "create_index" key, I get the following:

```
users
institution
lastname
    firstname
__name__
```

In this list, "users" is the collection, while institution, lastname, and firstname are fields of users. I believe these fields all appear in the collection -- save '__ name __' -- so I'm not quite sure which requested entity isn't found.

Any tips?

Many thanks.

Comment: I had same issue, turned out clicking the link from VSCode adds some extra characters at the end of the URL. I copy pasted the URL in the browser and it worked